# Ruby Binary Search Code is Not Returning Expected Results

Tags: ruby, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a binary search method in Ruby and have found a strange situation in which my code doesn't return what I expect it to when I add two numbers together and divide them by two in the elsif statement.

When I give the method a target of 1-3 and an array of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] then the method works and I get the index of the target I want.

When I give the method a target of 4, I get an infinite loop because the middle = first + last / 2 code is returning 5 rather than the expected 3. I even tried to print a 7/2 result and I got 3, but when it's pulling in the values, it returns 5.

When I give the method a target of 7-10, it breaks and says there's an undefined method '<' for nil:NilClass on line 12 (which is the line that the elsif is on).

```
def binary_search(target, array)
  middle = array.length / 2
  first = 0
  last = array.length - 1

  while first < last
    if array[middle] == target
      puts "we've found the target! middle is #{middle}"
      return true
    elsif array[middle] < target
      first = middle + 1
      middle = first + last / 2
      puts "we're in the elsif and middle is #{middle}"
    else
      last = middle - 1
      middle = first + last / 2
      puts "we're in the else and middle is now #{middle}"
    end
  end
  false
end

binary_search(4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Comment: It is to list your expectations simply (i.e. `given my_method(arg1, arg2) I expect it to return N` and then just list those, which leads to test driven development.  You said "it works" but didn't illustrate what the expected result is for your passing cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A prerequisite :

- `4 + 4 / 2` will give us 6. It's the equivalent of `4 + (4 / 2 )`.
- `(4 + 4) / 2` will give us 4.

The two statements are not equivalent.

On the two middle computation :

```rb
middle = first + last / 2
```

We do not have what we expect.

You are looking to divide `first` AND `last` by two.
So you will want to have :

```rb
middle = (first + last) / 2
```

If you replace `first + last / 2` by `(first + last) / 2`, your script will give us :

```
binary_search(4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
we're in the else and middle is now 2
we're in the elsif and middle is 3
we've found the target! middle is 3
 => true
```